# Arduino how to detect if a key is held down or not

Tags: arduino, keyboard

I'm trying to detect whether a key is pressed down or not.

I have a digispark connected to a rotary encoder that together form a volume control wheel. The thing is I want to change what rotating the encoder does without hard coding it, so i made a program in c# that communicates with the Arduino with the unused keyboard keys f13-f14, but if I hardcode those keys instead of the volume keys.

When I plug in the device in a computer that does not have the program the Arduino is useless. So I needed to find a way to communicate with the Arduino and tell it the program is there. This was hard because the digispark has no serial support.

But what if I use those unused keys, let's say f15 as a Boolean. I need code for the digispark(which is basically an Arduino) to find out whether f15 is held down or not(true or false).